# AsyncTask and Background Thread when to Use

Tags: android

What is the difference between AsyncTask and Background Thread. Which should be preferred or any scenarios to use these?

What I am trying to achieve right now is Will be sending request to server when user goes on a specific activity and display the data received on the same activity? The data received may be images or some text which I need to display in TextView or ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `AsyncTask` is basically a wrapper class for a Java thread.  It provides a convenient mechanism for executing one-time blocking operations.  Background threads are more useful when you have a task that's long-lasting and/or permanent to the entire course of the `Activity` (although I suppose you could implement `AsyncTask` to be permanent and just update the UI through the progress mechanism).

In your case, I would implement an `AsyncTask`.  Do your request in `doInBackground()` then update the UI in `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. A `AsyncTask` is a background thread. It's an implementation which helps you to perform tasks in background. Read its [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and you will see ;-)